# Stream is so laggy

Tags: twitch

I have started my streaming career 3 days ago. And when I watch back my streams they are really bad. Not voice quality or my English spelling but my laggy video. I have got about 3 - 7 people on my channel watching me and honestly I am very happy after 3 days. I am playing games from BlueStacks and streaming via OBS.

My internet is good on speedtest.net it is like this: 
-download speed: 94.9 Mb/s
-upload speed: 90.4 Mb/s

so I think that my problem is not in my internet connection.

I have MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, early 2015) with 2,7 GHz Intel Core i5. So what do you think guys. Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the issue is connected to either your encoding settings or your advanced settings, I recommend watching an instructional video on what should work for twitch.

For reference, these are my settings for twitch streaming (I have included video settings also just in case)

[image: Advanced settings tab]
[image: Encoding settings tab]
[image: Video settings tab]